# Expected Value of an AR(1) process

Tags: time-series, expected-value, stationarity, autoregressive

I saw the answer on [this post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30213/how-to-find-the-formula-for-the-half-life-of-an-ar1-process-using-the-ornstei) and got confused about a couple things in its explanation.

Mainly, I am unsure of

1. How the poster immediately knows the process $X_t = c+\phi_1 Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ is weakly stationary. Or is it just an assumption that is made?
2. How the poster goes from $E_t[X_{t+h}] = E_t[\alpha X_{t+h-1}+\epsilon_t] = \alpha^hX_t$

Answer (score 1):

1. This AR(1) process is WSS by [definition](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Autoregressive_model#/Example:_An_AR(1)_process). So, it is also *weakly stationary*. Of course, assuming $|\phi_1|<1$ as the poster suggests.
2. I simply follow the definitions and the notation in the post:

   $E_t[Y_{t+h}]=E_t[\phi_1Y_{t+h-1}+\epsilon_{t+h}]=E_t[\phi_1^2Y_{t+h-2}+\epsilon_{t+h}+\phi_1\epsilon_{t+h-1}]=E_t[\phi^hY_{t}]+\sum_{m=0}^{h-1}{\phi_1^mE_t[\epsilon_{t+h-m}}]=E_t[\phi^hY_t]=\phi^hY_t$, because expectation of noise is 0.

Comment: What does WSS stand for?

Comment: Wide-Sense-Stationary